# MYSQL Too many connections error will not go away

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm getting a MySQL "Too many connections" error in a C++ program running on Ubuntu Linux.

This is the code that gets the error (it's inside a method that returns the mysql error, if any):

```
MYSQL connect;
mysql_init(&connect);
if (!mysql_real_connect(&connect,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0))
{
    return mysql_error(&connect);
}
```

This code keeps returning the string "Too many connections."

I'm wondering if this is actually some other error. This program has been working for months before I got this error. When the error first appeared it was because I had run the program against several thousand updates/reads and so yes, it's highly likely that I used up the available connections. The problem is, I can't find a way to release them, if that's what it is.

Here is what I have tried:

- FLUSH HOSTS;
- FLUSH TABLES;
- restarting MYSQL
- rebooting the machine    altogether

It has been over 12 hours since this error first appeared, so if it is the connections then nothing is being reset/released. I would have thought rebooting the machine would have released something.

Comment: Just a quick comment. This question is not asking how to code the C++. I am of course closing the connection and releasing the pointer. My question is about how to get MYSQL to reset itself. This program will no longer run because there is some kind of internal state in MYSQL that continues to think there are too many connections, even after it has been idle for over 12 hours and the machine rebooted.

Comment: See edited version of my answer.

Comment: Thanks Bitmap, I'll try increasing the max_connections setting. Only thing is, this doesn't answer the question in my mind of how to reset the connections. Surely there must be some way to reset the connections in MySQL. Does it really hang on to all connections forever, even after reboot? Wouldn't that mean I can never, ever get rid of my connections? That part doesn't make sense to me

Comment: No - it depends on how your client applications are re-attempting connections. If they're eagerly retrying connection - then that could be the issue. You can `sudo pkill MySQL` to terminate and detach listening and established MySQL connections. You can debug the connections using by issuing - `netstat -apn | grep mysql | grep -i established` to see all established MySQL connections

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll try those options. I just got pulled onto another task so will check later!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [C.5.2.7. Too many connections.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html)

**View all MySQL connections.**

```
 netstat -apn | grep mysql | grep -i established
```

## Tips

- Build and return connection object only when connection pointer is null or connection to DB is unavailable.
- Use one connection pool for the entirety of the session.
- Close the connection at the end of each session and release/clean the connection pointer.
- Increase `max_connections=#` in /etc/mysql/my.cnf or restart MySQL with `--max_connections=#`

Comment: Thanks. I used this and determined that there were no current connections. After a bit more digging, what was happening was that there were a lot of connections being opened quickly. I'd thought that because the calls were happening in a loop the connection was being released in time. Previous runs of the program had never encountered this "patch of data" so this was the first time the error came up but... it was a problem with the program after all :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close connection when you are done with them.

Consider reusing connections or connection pooling.